"But Aberfan has scooped out the core of him, stretched it thin and catapulted it into the wild blue yonder."
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part I, Aberfan, chapter 11)

And then, at the dinner dance, with that kiss, he dared to believe they had a future. But Aberfan has scooped out the core of him, stretched it thin and catapulted it into the wild blue yonder. Maybe that's why he's here , to try and get himself back.

What do you understand by "stretched it thin" in this context? I take it to mean something like "the core of him was stretched like a string or an elastic band". What does the author want to say with this figurative language?

Are we going to go through the entire book like this? This is a metaphor and not very successful in fact. If you take a scoop and scoop out something from something, it normally would not lend itself to being stretched thin and then catapulted. Take a loaf of bread, scoop out the core, stretch it thin. Fine, You get a flat piece of dough. Not easy to "catapult" that. He trying to provide an image of "stuff" being shot with a catapult into the blue yonder.

I’m voting to close this question because not an English learning question.  There is no special use of English here, the same metaphor could be used in any language.

@Lambie - I can imagine it working very well with the inner tube of a cycle tyre (tire), pull it out long and thin, then let go  (or it breaks!) and SNAP! or WHEEE! In fact when I was a kid we used a cross sectional cut of an innter tube as the elastic band part of a catapult.Powerful enough to smash windows and put someone's eye out.

@ James K. - "I’m voting to close this question because not an English learning question" - Isn't understanding an English phrase learning English even if it is somewhat odd or unusual?

Yes, some here seem to want to close all kinds of questions. Admittedly, this is more literary but I think it's fine.

@MichaelHarvey Sure, but you wouldn't catapult the actual inner tube of the tire...My point is that the metaphor does not work well and I explained enough why it does not.

@Lambie - if you hold something elastic and pull the other end so that it is very stretched, and then let go of both ends at once, it will go flying. Catapult: hurl or launch (something) with or as if with a catapult. (Oxford Languages). My belief is that the metaphor does work well and I have explained, in my turn, why it does.

@MichaelHarvey I don't think that removing the inner tube from a tire would be called: scooping out the core of a tire.  Scooping out something is like ice cream or dough or dirt (from a pot) or scooping the letters up off the floor. Also, to scoop out a person's core is pretty gruesome, even as a metaphor. Generally, what is scooped could not be stretched out. Oh and make sure to quote the dictionary at me. That surely will help...

@Lambie - do you actually know what happened at Aberfan on 21 October 1966? I think that being closely involved in the immediate aftermath and after could easily scoop out a person's core, spiritually and emotionally.

@MichaelHarvey The problem is not scooping out the core. The problem that idea + the rest of it.  Yes, I do know and also saw the documentary on it.

You should not crosspost the same question on two English language websites. Why did you do that? On EL&U the same identical question posted only two hours later: "But Aberfan has scooped out the core of him, stretched it thin and catapulted it into the wild blue yonder."

Simple explanation: James K's comment is a negative response  and I worried the question  would be closed, actually.

Focusing on the meanings of to be stretched thin (and avoiding interpretation of the string of metaphors) ...
To be "stretched thin" is to be, or to feel, tenuous, flimsy, weak, insufficient, approaching a limit of some kind.
It isn't as specific as an elastic band like a rubber band, but there is the sense that one's fiscal or, as here, emotional resiliency is at or near its limits.

I've mostly seen "stretched thin" be synonymous to "spread thin" - to be insufficient, particularly because of multiple things demanding one's attention or resources at once (by analogy to being pulled in multiple directions, or trying to cover a wide area). The author seems to use it to mean something like "pushed to breaking point", which I don't think is the common understanding of that idiom - but it seems that the author is playing fast and loose with their metaphors in general.

Play fast and loose in this context  is a harsh word, isn't it?

Maciej can respond, but I wouldn't criticize the author's use of "stretched thin" to include what we often call "inner resources" (i.e. emotional fortitude).  The images the string of metaphors presents are quite grotesque, but perhaps that is fitting, given the nature of the catastrophe.

@philphil a little critical, I'm not a fan of the author's style. But it's more of an observation that - based on this and the other question I've answered about this book - she seems to be using a lot of metaphors and chains of metaphors, often in non-obvious ways that aren't idiomatic in English and require the reader to interpret them on their own. Whether you find it tedious or poetic is a matter of opinion.
